# liferay 7 web content template vm serviceLocator not work

Tags: templates, velocity, liferay-7, service-locator, web-content

I create a template for web content using vm. But the *serviceLocator* does not work.
I added

```
    journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```

to my portal-ext.properties file, but it did not help.

I did not find the *journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables* property in the original portal.properties file.

How to make serviceLocator work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `velocity.engine.restricted.variables=`

Also, note that Velocity is not the best option going forward FreeMarker would be a better way to go.

Comment: Why would you say that FM is a better option than Velocity?

Comment: For me, the killer feature is the option to use the java tag libraries that make your life easier. The product supports both of the languages but I think it moves more towards the FM.